# Django app on Heroku: Issues with continuous development AFTER deployment

Tags: django, heroku

So, I just updated my Django app for Heroku and GIT pushed my master branch to production for the first time. Works well. However, when I try to run my app locally on the same master branch, I get all these errors. Understandably, since I've updated the settings file specifically for production on Heroku.

My question is the following:

**If I want to continue my development locally and periodically push stable versions to production, do I need to maintain 2 settings.py files? (ie, one for dev and one for prod)**

I'm a beginner, so sorry if this question sounds ridiculous, but I can't seem to find any clear information about this, after reading Heroku's documentation about deployment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

I just want to be able to continue running my development locally.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, typically you will have one settings.py for local development, and one for production. Optionally you could also have an additional settings.py for a staging environment. good practice is to have a base settings.py with shared settings for both local and prod. Then you extend from that file in your production and local setting files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the biggest issue between the development and production environments is difference in databases they use. So use environment variables for both development and production modes.

1. Create an .env file at project root

```
SECRET_KEY='somesupersecretivesecretkey'
DEBUG=True #set to false while pushing to Heroku, leave at True while working in development 
DB_NAME='dbname'
DB_USER='dbuser'
DB_PASSWORD='dbpassword'
DB_HOST='127.0.0.1'
MODE='dev' #set to 'prod' in production
ALLOWED_HOSTS='.localhost', '.herokuapp.com', '.127.0.0.1'
DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

2. In your project settings (you only need one), check which mode you are in (production or development) and choose which database to use (the one installed in Heroku or the one on your machine). Assuming you are using Postgres, something like this:

```py
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config,Csv

MODE=config("MODE", default="dev")
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
# development
if config('MODE')=="dev":
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
           'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
           'USER': config('DB_USER'),
           'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
           'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
           'PORT': '',
       }

   }
# production
else:
   DATABASES = {
       'default': dj_database_url.config(
           default=config('DATABASE_URL')
       )
   }

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv())
```

3. Before pushing your code to Heroku, after changing the `.env` variable appropriately, run `heroku config:set $(cat .env | sed '/^$/d; /#[[:print:]]*$/d')` to enforce the database changes in heroku's dashboard... Hope it helps

Comment: @ Mercurial So after playing around with the code for a bit, I managed to make it work like you suggested! So my next question is: what's the best practice to toggle your mode between production and development? Do you simply change MODE in your .env environment variable to "dev" or "prod" accordingly? So technically, that is the only variable you update regularly with since everything else is updated as per the if statement?

Comment: @MaximVallee great to hear... Yeah, that is the only variable you need to change to switch back and forth... To make things easier, after the initial push to production, you could remove .env from version control if you are sure that you don't need to change it again. Then, you could change it back to 'dev' mode. This way, even if you push your code, the .env file on Heroku will still state ```mode='prod'```... sth like 1. ```git rm --cached .env```, 2. add .env to ```.gitignore``` 3. stage and push everything else